# progressr problems on shiny app running on EDP server

Tags: r, shiny, progress-bar

I´m running a shiny app on an EDP server with the rocker/shiny:4.2.2 image.
The shiny app uses several future.apply funcitionalities and shows progress by a *progressr* progress bar.

```
withProgressShiny(
    message = "Collecting results ",
    detail = "initialization",
    {
      p <- progressor(steps = 100)
      counter = 0
      while(counter < 100){
        counter=counter+1
        p(message = "searching")
      }
    })
```

The progress bar is working really good with different future::plans (sequential, multisession, multicore) on my local machine but is not running on the server. The server just shows the "initialization" part of the progressr function during the whole while-loop but not the "searching" part.

Session info shows same versions of all used packages including R-version.

Seems to be a problem with the progressor() but not with the withProgressShiny() part.

Any suggestions how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem in the fundamentals of progressr package:

R session on EDP Server was non-interactive so

```
interactive()
FALSE
```

The progressr package needs an interactive session by default. By actively setting

```
progressr.enable = TRUE
```

in the R options for the image I overcome this problem and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem except the server I am using is shinapps.io. I was able to modify Marcel's solution to fix the problem by simply placing

```
    options(progressr.enable = TRUE)
```

by where I load the packages (notably, putting "progressr.enable = TRUE"
in the same location as above or in the server() function did NOT resolve the problem). e.g.:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(progressr)
    handlers("progress")
    #add it here:
    options(progressr.enable = TRUE)
    
    ui <- fluidPage( ... )
    server <- function( ... )
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```